# Convnet in 1D gives accuracy of 50%: I can't figure out why

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a convnet in 1D for timeseries binary classification. I tried to build the network, but what I get is not more than 50% accuracy: basically, it's completely random.

Looking at the weights, I figured out that in the first layer of my network the weights don't see anything – some easy-to-spot spikes in the timeseries.

`print(x.shape, y.shape)`
  "(1965, 100, 1) (1965, 2)"

```
#My model
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters = 1,
                        kernel_size = 10,
                        activation = 'relu',
                        input_shape=(timesteps,1)))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1,
                       activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 91, 1)             11        
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d (Global (None, 1)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 2         
=================================================================
Total params: 13
Trainable params: 13
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
    model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop',
                  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])

    network = model.fit(x, y[:,0],
                        epochs = 20,
                        batch_size = 32,
                        shuffle = True)
```

```
    Epoch 1/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 211us/sample - loss: 0.6929 - accuracy: 0.5247
Epoch 2/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 78us/sample - loss: 0.6925 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 3/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 79us/sample - loss: 0.6922 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 4/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 79us/sample - loss: 0.6920 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 5/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 77us/sample - loss: 0.6919 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 6/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 0.6917 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 7/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 78us/sample - loss: 0.6917 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 8/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 76us/sample - loss: 0.6916 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 9/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 79us/sample - loss: 0.6916 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 10/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 77us/sample - loss: 0.6916 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 11/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 77us/sample - loss: 0.6916 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 12/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 77us/sample - loss: 0.6916 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 13/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 83us/sample - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 14/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 81us/sample - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 15/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 81us/sample - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 16/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 79us/sample - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 17/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 80us/sample - loss: 0.6916 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 18/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 81us/sample - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 19/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 81us/sample - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5288
Epoch 20/20
1965/1965 [==============================] - 0s 81us/sample - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5288
```

This is all I get.

---

I tried to build a small conv1D "by hand", and it shows that it can actually find the spikes in the data.

I believe I am doing some small error, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you please share the results upto epoch 20/20

Comment: I would assume that global max pooling is the problem. Note that this zeroes out all gradients except the one for the highest activation, making it difficult to learn anything, especially since the weights are initially random so the maximum activation is almost completely uninformative.

Comment: Please increase the number of filters as well as number of epochs

Comment: Thank you all. I tried to do what you suggested long ago, and nothing worked. As I wrote, I found that the problem lies in the first layer, where all of the weights come out at random.

Comment: But I still cannot find a solution to it. This is the first time I am building a 1Dconvnet, so I still haven't grasped completely all of it. I really hope I am doing some sort of "rookie mistake".

Comment: Could you share some of the training data?